# Positioning a div in navigation

Tags: html, css

On my website I have a navigation with a news tab. If I post new things, there appears a small notification above the news tab (similar to iOS).
It looks pretty fine, but on my mobile version the positioning of the notification doesn't look the same (I can't find out why).
How do I have to adjust the css?
Here is my website: http://calendar.pineappledeveloper.com 
(You can pull the browser window smaller to see the mobile version)

Comment: Can you post an image of the expected output?

Comment: @media screen and (max-width: 400px)
nav ul li #notification {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    top: -1em;
    left: -1em;}

Comment: Hi Kit Fung! Thank you very much, this worked fine for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can fix that using `@media` and `max-width`

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
.element {
    /* Your changes here */
}
}
```

Add changes and all should be fine.